# jQuery dialog adding many css-classes on open then not removing them on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

My jQuery dialogues work perfectly fine except that **the following is appended every time the dialog is opened**.

`js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths`

They do not get removed when you close. However when you open the dialog again it'll re-add these classes. So eventually the html element's class attribute become half a page pretty quickly.

**Dialog Setup**:

```
$(dialogSelector).dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Current Schedule",
    width: 450,
    height: 500
});
```

**Full function:**

```
function ViewScheduleDialog(dialogSelector, href, id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: "GET",
        data: { SelectedID: id },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $(dialogSelector).html(data);
            $(dialogSelector).dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: "Current Schedule",
                width: 450,
                height: 500
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a reason it is adding these css-classes and not removing them?

**I've also tried:**

Making the dialog do the above *Dialog Setup* on doc-ready, then only open/close when my link is clicked. The html element is still mass populated with css-classes.

**Technologies:**

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- Jquery v1.10.2 & JQuery-UI 1.10.4
- Bootstrap v3.0.0 (jQuery-UI is being loaded after Bootstrap)

Comment: Where is  the code where you hide and show the dialog?

Comment: That's effectively it, I guess I'll add more but I'm just using the X in the upper right of the dialog and using the snippet I showed to Open.

Comment: The snippet you showed creates a dialog; it doesn't just open it. After it's created their is an open function: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open

Comment: I switched it to create the dialog with autoOpen to false on document.ready and then use .dialog("open") but the same thing happens. It still appends those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you double check that all of the proper `.css` files are included in your code.

Have you tried to use `jquery` to remove the class? Something like this:

```
$('#dialogSelector').removeClass('open');
```

Comment: This does fix the issue, however, it doesn't quite answer my question since I'm asking why they're being appended every time I open a dialog.

Comment: My guess would be that everytime the dialog is opened you call `$(dialogSelector).html(data);` which keeps appending the data

Comment: How would that affect the `<html>` element? It's selecting a div on the page `div#schedule` to be exact and putting the returned html into it. So unless I'm cursed it shouldn't be touching the `<html>` element.